# Why risk Cole's life by sending him on missions?

Tags: 12-monkeys-2015

In the TV series *12 Monkeys*, it's stated in the pilot that Cole's destiny is to travel through time.  However, it seems like the rules of the show allow time to change due to time travel.  In the 'present' of 2043, Cole still leaves the bunker to go on missions to gather intel for future trips into the past.  As seen in S1E2 *Mentally Divergent*, the present is not a safe place to wander around in.  It would seem prudent to not let Cole go on recon missions in the present so as to ensure his safety for time travel missions.

Why is Cole allowed to leave the bunker to go on missions in 2043?

Comment: Because tv/plot?

Comment: Trying to resist urge to make negative remark about a needless TV series ruining one of my favorite movies :P I'll apply my trusty "does not exist" mental filter here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just *some missions* missions. It is *recon* as you put it yourself and (so far) it's the places relevant to the past missions directly or indirectly. So somewhere he (and only he) will (or might) visit in the past.

So visiting in person gives an edge. And keeps the whole future–past connectedness going, so that future is actually *meaningful* part of plot and not just something somewhat unkempt guy keeps falling out of.

Comment: Hi, not bad but do you have some source materials behind that answer ?

Comment: Honestly I feel it's _more_ of a storytelling mechanism, but not _too_ implausible. :)